# Scrapy Playwright get date by clicking button

Tags: python, scrapy, playwright

I am trying to scrape [google flights](https://www.google.com/travel/flights/search?tfs=CBwQAhooagwIAxIIL20vMDE3N3oSCjIwMjItMDctMDNyDAgDEggvbS8wNmM2MhooagwIAxIIL20vMDZjNjISCjIwMjItMDctMjJyDAgDEggvbS8wMTc3enABggELCP___________wFAAUgBmAEB&tfu=EgYIARABGAA&curr=EUR) using scrapy and scrapy playwright. There is a selecting date input filed and I'd like to get range of input dates then collect other data from that page then again change the date and fetch the data and so on and so forth. Right now I have a script which is working but not exactly as I wanted to work

Here is the recent code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_playwright.page import PageCoroutine
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class PwExSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "pw_ex"

    headers = {
        "authority": "www.google.com",
        "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
        "accept-language": "en,ru;q=0.9",
        "cache-control": "max-age=0",
        # Requests sorts cookies= alphabetically
        # 'cookie': 'ANID=AHWqTUmN_Nw2Od2kmVHB-V-BPMn7lUDKjrsMYy6hJGcTF6v7U8u5YjJPArPDJI4K; SEARCH_SAMESITE=CgQIhpUB; CONSENT=YES+shp.gws-20220509-0-RC1.en+FX+229; OGPC=19022519-1:19023244-1:; SID=LwgAuUOC2U32iRLEjSQUdzx-18XGenx489M7BtkpBNDmZ_obyU799NLH7re0HlcH0tGNpg.; __Secure-1PSID=LwgAuUOC2U32iRLEjSQUdzx-18XGenx489M7BtkpBNDmZ_obMMyHAVo5IhVZXcHbzyERTw.; __Secure-3PSID=LwgAuUOC2U32iRLEjSQUdzx-18XGenx489M7BtkpBNDmZ_obxoNZznCMM25HAO4zuDeNTw.; HSID=A24bEjBTX5lo_2EDh; SSID=AXpmgSwtU6fitqkBi; APISID=PhBKYPpLmXydAQyJ/AzHdHtibgwX2VeVmr; SAPISID=bR71_zlABgKzGVWh/Ae0bo1S1RV74H5p0z; __Secure-1PAPISID=bR71_zlABgKzGVWh/Ae0bo1S1RV74H5p0z; __Secure-3PAPISID=bR71_zlABgKzGVWh/Ae0bo1S1RV74H5p0z; OTZ=6574663_36_36__36_; 1P_JAR=2022-07-02-19; NID=511=V3Tw5Rz0i058NG-nDiH7T8ePoRgiQTzp1MzxA-fzgJxrMiyJmXPbOtsbbIGWUZSY47b9zRw5E_CupzMBaUwWxUfxduldltqHJ8KDFsbW4F_WbUTzaHCFnwoQqEbckzWXG-12Sj94-L-Q8AIFd9UTpOzgi1jglT2pmEUzAdJ2uvO70QZ577hdlROJ4RMxl-FMefvoSJOhJOBEsW2_8H5vffLkJX-PNvl8U9gq_vyUqb_FYGx7zFBfZ5v8YPmQFFia523NrlK_J9VhdyEwGw5B3eaicpWZ8BPTEBFlYyPlnKr5PBhKeHCBL1jjc5N9WOrXHIko0hSPuQLAV8hIaiAwjHdt9ISJM3Lv7-MTiFhz7DJhCH7l72wxJtjpjw2p4gpDA5ewL5EfnhXss6sd; SIDCC=AJi4QfEvHIMmVfhjcEMP5ngU_yyfA1iSDYNmmbNKnGq3w0EspvCZaZ8Hd1oobxtDOIsY1LjJDS8; __Secure-1PSIDCC=AJi4QfEB_vOMIx2aSaNP7YGkLcpMBxMMJQLwZ5MuHjcFPrWipfycBV4V4yjT9dtifeYHAXLU_1I; __Secure-3PSIDCC=AJi4QfFhA4ftN_yWMxTXryTwMwdIdfLZzsAyzZM0lPkjhUrrRYnQwHzg87pPFf12QdgLEvpEFFc',
        "referer": "https://www.google.com/",
        "sec-ch-ua": '" Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="100", "Yandex";v="22"',
        "sec-ch-ua-arch": '"x86"',
        "sec-ch-ua-bitness": '"64"',
        "sec-ch-ua-full-version": '"22.5.0.1879"',
        "sec-ch-ua-full-version-list": '" Not A;Brand";v="99.0.0.0", "Chromium";v="100.0.4896.143", "Yandex";v="22.5.0.1879"',
        "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
        "sec-ch-ua-model": '""',
        "sec-ch-ua-platform": '"Linux"',
        "sec-ch-ua-platform-version": '"5.4.0"',
        "sec-ch-ua-wow64": "?0",
        "sec-fetch-dest": "document",
        "sec-fetch-mode": "navigate",
        "sec-fetch-site": "same-origin",
        "sec-fetch-user": "?1",
        "upgrade-insecure-requests": "1",
        "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.143 Safari/537.36",
    }

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(
            "https://www.google.com/travel/flights/search?tfs=CBwQAhooagwIAxIIL20vMDE3N3oSCjIwMjItMDctMDNyDAgDEggvbS8wNmM2MhooagwIAxIIL20vMDZjNjISCjIwMjItMDctMjJyDAgDEggvbS8wMTc3enABggELCP___________wFAAUgBmAEB&tfu=EgYIARABGAA&curr=EUR",
            headers=self.headers,
            meta=dict(
                playwright=True,
                playwright_include_page=True,
                playwright_page_coroutines=[
                    PageCoroutine("wait_for_selector", "h3.zBTtmb.ZSxxwc"),
                ],
            ),
        )

    async def parse(self, response):
        page = response.meta["playwright_page"]

        for i in range(0, 5):

            html = response.text
            # print(html)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
            search_date = soup.find_all("input")[-6]["value"]
            await page.click(
                "#yDmH0d > c-wiz.zQTmif.SSPGKf > div > div:nth-child(2) > c-wiz > div > c-wiz > div.PSZ8D.EA71Tc > div.Ep1EJd > div > div.rIZzse > div.bgJkKe.K0Tsu > div > div > div.dvO2xc.k0gFV > div > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > div.oSuIZ.YICvqf.kStSsc.ieVaIb > div > div.WViz0c.CKPWLe.U9gnhd.Xbfhhd > button"
            )

            yield {
                "search_date": search_date,
            }
```

The above script just fetching `"Sun, Jul 3"` not all the dates in the range:

```
[
    {
        "search_date": "Sun, Jul 3"
    },
    {
        "search_date": "Sun, Jul 3"
    },
    {
        "search_date": "Sun, Jul 3"
    },
    {
        "search_date": "Sun, Jul 3"
    },
    {
        "search_date": "Sun, Jul 3"
    }
]
```

Desired ouput:

```
[
{"search_date": "Sun, Jul 3"},
{"search_date": "Mon, Jul 4"},
{"search_date": "Tue, Jul 5"},
{"search_date": "Wed, Jul 6"},
{"search_date": "Thu, Jul 7"}
]
```

Please can anyone here help me out here with that I am pretty new to scrapy playwright. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(0, 5):

            html = response.text
            # print(html)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
            search_date = soup.find_all("input")[-6]["value"]
            await page.click(
                "#yDmH0d > c-wiz.zQTmif.SSPGKf > div > div:nth-child(2) > c-wiz > div > c-wiz > div.PSZ8D.EA71Tc > div.Ep1EJd > div > div.rIZzse > div.bgJkKe.K0Tsu > div > div > div.dvO2xc.k0gFV > div > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > div.oSuIZ.YICvqf.kStSsc.ieVaIb > div > div.WViz0c.CKPWLe.U9gnhd.Xbfhhd > button"
            )

            yield {
                "search_date": search_date,
            }
```

This logic to extract all the dates in the range is incorrect. Understand the flow of

1. you make request to the flight page.
2. you get the response.
3. In parse method you are trying to extract the search date.

```
search_date = soup.find_all("input")[-6]["value"]
```

This line is only returning one date and not a list. Moreover, I don't understand the logic behind the for loop here. Because this piece of code is not making any further requests as you are trying to achieve with the extracted dates[mentioned in the question]

> Important thing to note here is, you have to got the entire html response in one go. You can now use [css selectors](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html) or soup to extract all the selected dates. Running the for loop for 5 times, doesn't solve any purpose, as you are executing the same information 5 times.

Use `response.css('<<Path to the dates in the select>>').getall()` to get all the dates you are looking for. Process the information further.

**Improvisation on the logic:**
You can improvise on the logic, I am not sure why you are extracting range of dates, when you can just extract the departure and return dates for the page. And make a request using them. Or Just extract the departure date and increment it and make another request using that date for further information.

Comment: How can I make another request using playwright pageboject?

Comment: Can you explain what exactly are you ultimately trying to extract from the website?

Comment: I am trying to get flight price, departure, arrival, flight date, airline name, air craft, flight number etc. Basically gather all the flight info and not just for one date but for range of dates.